# IE6 is rendering a period.. totally randomly. This period does not show in any other browsers. HELP!

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I just previewed my page in IE6 and for some reason it is rendering a period for absolutely not reason.  I looked in my html to make sure I didnt add an extra period on accident or something and was unable to find ANYthing.

http://cypresslakesfla.com/models-new.php

Take a look, make sure you have IE6 tester and you will see.  Anyone seen this problem before and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Where is this period I'm supposed to be looking for?  EDIT: found it, above the word "Options", to the right of each thumbnail picture.

Comment: On the bright side, that period is probably the least of your IE6 issues: the "Visit Our Communities" menu is 5/6th hidden, and the footer is invisible.  :-)

Comment: Validate your code: you have a load of unclosed tags and mis formated code.  Get it clean before you worry about IE6 or it doesn't stand a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see is an improperly closed `p` tag below the "Options" `h5`.